# How to add nil value to a NSArray in swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

NSArray.init(array: [Any])

NSArray has an initial function whose parameter is [Any]. But not [Any?], so, how to add a nil value to this array?

Comment: Why do you wish to use `NSArray` in Swift? Why not use a Swift array?

Comment: @rmaddy because save array to Core Data should be NSArray,so I must to use NSArray.

Comment: NSArray/NSMutableArray doesn't allow you to store `nil` values in the array.

Comment: @rmaddy so I saved an optional value such as   “var array: [[Int]?]()” and “NSArray(array: array)”, it just give me a warning said “Expression implicitly coerced from ‘[Int]?’ to Any, and it also work normally, so should I silence this warning?

Comment: `(NS)Array` is not supported by Core Data as attribute. Core Data uses `Set`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` don't allow you to store `nil` values in the array. This is why none of the Swift APIs allow optional values.

If you really need to something for nil, use `NSNull()` though I'm not 100% sure how that will work with Core Data.

And Swift actually does this for you. If you pass a Swift array of optionals, any `nil` values get converted to `NSNull`. Example:

```
var array = [Int?]()
array.append(4)
array.append(nil)
let nsa = array as NSArray
print(nsa) // (4, "<null>")
print(type(of: nsa[1])) // NSNull
```

Note that using `let nsa = NSArray(array: array)` instead of `let nsa = array as NSArray` worked without warning under Swift 4.0 but gives a warning as of Swift 4.1.

Comment: @CLOX You'll have a much easier time in the Swift world if you convert to Swift `Array` at the earliest possible time after fetching from CoreData,  and convert to NSArray at the latest possible time before pushing to CoreData.

Comment: @rmaddy: your example will get a warning at line 4, it said forced-unwrap can avoid.

Comment: Replace line 4 with `let nsa = array as NSArray`

Comment: @vacawama and CLOX I get no error or warning with the code I posted. It works as-is in an Xcode 9.2 (Swift 4.0) playground. But the suggested change is a good one none the less.

Comment: Xcode 9.3 (Swift 4.1) gives a warning **Expression implictly coerced from 'Int?' to Any**.  The 3 suggested *Fix*es do not work.

Comment: @vacawama Interesting. I haven't updated yet so I can test that. Does your suggested change fix the warning?

Comment: Yes.  There is no warning with my change, and the output is as you describe.  I'm downloading Xcode 9.3.1 at this moment, and will report what it does.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect this info.

Comment: Xcode 9.3.1 (Swift 4.1) is the same as Xcode 9.3, which isn't surprising since it's the same compiler version.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Xcode 9.3 beta, and type ‘array as NSArray’ can silence that warning.  Thanks again!

Comment: @vacawama The un-silenceable warning for `NSArray(array:)` [is a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2928) which [will be fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/14221) in Swift 4.2 (you'll need to say `let nsa = NSArray(array: array as [Any])` though to acknowledge the erasure of the optionals). But `as NSArray` is the preferable way to do a bridge in most cases.